# How to Get sql results in set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables. it's all are having a relationship with the related table as mentioned below :

```
Car_Info
Car_Model
Car_Color
```

Sql Query :

```
SELECT `CI`.`*`, `CM`.`*`, `CC`.`*` 
FROM
    `Car_Info` AS `CI` 
    INNER JOIN
        `Car_Model` AS `CM` 
        ON CM.car_id = CI.car_id 
    INNER JOIN
        `Car_Color` AS `CC` 
        ON CC.car_model_id = CM.car_model_id
```

Current results :

[image]

Expected results :

[image]

Expected results column value we can set null in a row for those columns.

Actually, I want this car list in dropdown like this way in HTML layout :

```
Bmw
 bmw x1
  black
  yellow
  pink
  red 
 bmw x1
  black
  yellow
  red
Audi
 Audi x1
  black
  red
```

Comment: I have removed the SQL Server tag, as this is clearly MySQL, and removed the PHP tag as I see nothing about the language in the above. Please only use the tags that are related to your question.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't have too much idea to get result in this format. @hassan

Comment: then what is the difference between current result & expected result, when generating the HTML, you still need to process row by row, just comparing NULL or equal with previous row. But you can always introduce variables to get expected result. What's more, you can even get result as JSON structure { BMW: { X1: [ "black", "yellow"], X2: [...] } }, will that be your option